# Clear Skies Dragon Shout Refuses To Clear Winterhold

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I finally got to the main quest, and got the Clear Skies shout. Got all 3 words. It works everywhere, but Winterhold.

I have a couple quests going in and around Winterhold. Everytime I visit Winterhold, it is ALWAYS snowing. I want to clear it out. But it does not work. The guards eventually ask me to stop shouting.

Does the shout only work in certain areas? And since the name of the place is Winterhold, does it always have to be snowing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not mentioned in any of the previous answers is that this is an identified bug, at least by the Unofficial Skyrim Special Edition Patch team.  Identified as bug # [19800](https://afktrack.afkmods.com/index.php?a=issues&i=19800).

> Clear Skies does not clear the weather in Winterhold despite all indications it should do so. This was due to a weather region setting that had snow storms set to 100%. This has been corrected to 99% snow storm and 1% cloudy, since the shout requires there to be a "pleasant" weather variety available. As a side effect of this, it will now be 1% possible in normal gameplay for Winterhold to have cloudy weather instead of a snow storm. (Bug #19800)

As this bug is fixed (and, for the record, I have the patch installed and it is definitely fixed), you can download the patch on Nexus by [Arthmoor](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/users/684492) for [Legendary Edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214), and you can download the patch on BethesdaNet by [Arthmoor](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim?author_username=Arthmoor) for [PC](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2947658), [XBox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2947804) and for [PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4073181).

Answer (score 3):

There are other things going on in Winterhold that could be affecting the weather. If you follow through the mage guild / college quest, you'll get an idea of what's troubling that region, and it's possible they'll elaborate further in DLC.

It's likely by design that you cannot use the shout there.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, if you use the shout inside the Courtyard of the college, the weather clears and stays clear as long as you don't step out of college grounds... Weather turns back to snow almost as soon as you step back on the bridge to Winterhold...

Might be linked to the fact that the town was destroyed by the elements while the college hardly suffered. 
The most likely explanation is that the town is indeed cursed, and the college warded against the curse somehow, and the Thu'um is not strong enough to overcome the curse without the help of the college's wards.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the big blue mana pool before the entrance to the Hall of Elements, get in it and shout up, the sky will clear for a bit but then go back to snowing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use all three words, use the first one with a short shout then right when the Cooldown is up use it again... Works everytime...

Answer (score 0):

Use the shout at the college. The town may not be high enough altitude for your shout to reach the sky to clear it.